# QTextStream readAll() removes Newlines

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcore

I am using `QFile` and `QTextStream` to first read a file and then write the read contents unmodified back into the same file. Here is the code:

```
QFile inFile("file.txt");
if(!inFile.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
{
    qCritical() << "ERROR: Unable to open input file: " << "file.txt";
    exit(1);
}
QTextStream inStream(&inFile);
QString fileContents = inStream.readAll();
inFile.close();

QFile outFile("file.txt");
if(!outFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
{
    qCritical() << "ERROR: Unable to open output file: " << "file.txt";
    exit(1);
}

QTextStream outSream(&outFile);
outSream << fileContents;
outFile.close();
```

However, this transforms the **file.txt** given below:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

into

```
12345
```

i.e. newlines are getting removed in this process. Why is this happening? How can I prevent it?

Comment: It works as expected on Debian 8 (no transformation occurs, output looks exactly like input). Do you use Windows ? Maybe different codecs are used for reading and writing !? Try the same without the `QFile::Text` flag to avoid interpretation of any control characters ("\n", etc.).

Comment: Post hex dumps of both files, if possible. We need to get a good look at what exactly line terminators were and what they become (assuming they don't disappear completely).

Comment: Works for me.  Two things to try: firstly, `qDebug() << fileContents;` after reading (will help identify whether reading or writing is transforming characters); secondly, write to a new file, and dump both - e.g. `od -c 33997523.txt` gives me `1  \n   2  \n   3  \n   4  \n   5  \n` for both input and output file.

Answer (score 2):

The `QIODevice::Text` flag passed to `open()` tells `Qt` to **convert Windows-style line terminators (`\r\n`) into C++-style terminators (`\n`)**.
Are you operating in **Windows**? You should be able to see the `\r\n` in a binary editor on the input and the output file.

Comment: But since both inFile and outFile are opened in the same mode, the resulting file should have CRLF line terminators. Unless they weren't really CRLF line terminators in the original file.

Comment: Sergey, you are right, it should do (I failed to see the QIODevice::Text on the output file. Actually, for me with Windows 64 bit Qt5.5.1, it does work as expected. A binary dump of the input is needed, probably there is only a \n on the input, not a \r\n.

Comment: I don't think having only `\n` in the input would delete it completely. But maybe it's some weird file with old-style Mac CR-only newlines (and I'm not sure even those will break) or maybe there is something wrong with how he prints the files after the program is finished.

Comment: Having only '\n' in the input does delete it completely on Windows (tested it here!)

Comment: Interesting. I remember that `QTextStream` works in a weird way when combined with `QIODevice::Text`, maybe that's another side of that weirdness. Guess that `QTextStream` is meant to handle newlines by itself.

Answer (score 1):

About `QIODevice::Text` in openMode the official document says.

> When reading, the end-of-line terminators are translated to '\n'. When writing, the end-of-line terminators are translated to the local encoding, for example '\r\n' for Win32.

It says Win32,while working on Win64,Qt5.8 I found it works differently.
With `QIODevice::Text` in openMode, `QIODevice::readAll()` remove all `'\r','\t'`.

And talk about `\n`,they are replaced by `\r` whatever openMode is using. 
May be removed if using `QIODevice::Text` mode.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not use QFile::Text or QIODevice::Text, if you are reading, just use QIODevice::ReadOnly , in that way you can also figure out the exact line ending used and handle them appropriately. I had this problem with Mac(CR) or '\r' line ending while opening with QIODevice::Text.